# How to stop Salesforce Email Processor error

Tags: email, case, email2case

I have been getting countless emails with this error ever since I was assigned a Case on my Salesforce account.

Error message below:

> An error occured while trying to deliver the attached email.
> You may wish to report the following information to the owner of [e-mail redacted].

> Too many retries

> The inbound email could not be processed.

[This](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A97ViSAJ) trailblazer community thread describes the exact same problem that I am facing, but there is no solution listed there.

I have already checked My Email Settings and My Email to Salesforce, the settings are standard but I have unsubscribed from Subscriptions and added my email as Acceptable Email Address.

Answer (score 0):

This normally has to do with email-to-case. Remove the forwarding email address in your email settings and that should stop it.

Good Day!